# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification not firing in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8

I am trying to listen to the notification `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` but for some reason its not getting fired in iOS8 and I see some undocumented notifications (`UIKeyboardCandidateCorrectionDidChangeNotification`) showing up in the console.

Anyone facing same error?

Comment: Show your actual code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Declare

```
BOOL _keyboardWillhide = YES;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _keyboardWillHide = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    _keyboardWillHide = NO;
    return YES;    
}

if (_keyboardWillHide) {
    //Do something if keyboard is hide
    ...
}
//set back to Yes if keyboard willHide
_keyBoardWillHide = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in Xcode 6.0.1 building for iOS8 on an iPhone 5s. Currently, the simulator in Xcode 6.0.1 doesn't seem to be opening keyboards.

Here is the code I use to register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

This works with the system and custom keyboards running on an actual device.  Hopefully there is a typo in your code somewhere.  If not, feel free to post what you are comfortable with for a second set of eyes.

Comment: Wow... thanks for the down-vote.  Was only trying to help.  You might want to consider explaining your problem in more detail because the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is firing fine for most people in iOS8.